# How can I get my Tkinter quiz app to work with any .csv file a user enters?

Tags: python, csv, class, tkinter

I made a Tkinter quiz application, and the code is below. The MainQuizApp.py controls the main flow, and the questions_model.py models reading the quiz questions from a .csv file. Right now, my code is hardcoded where everything comes from the questions.csv file I created while writing my program, but I'd like for my app to let the user type in which .csv file they'd like the quiz app to load questions from. Right now, the entry widget on the main screen would be where a user would type in the .csv file name (it's read-only/hardcoded to questions.csv at the moment), and after hitting Load and Start, the quiz app would run with those questions instead of always questions.csv. Any help with how I can make this happen?

MainQuizApp.py

```
import questions_model as qm

# import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox # necessary for the Instructions dialogue box
from tkinter import ttk # necessary for the Progressbar widget

# import time
import time
import datetime

# create MainQuizApp class
class MainQuizApp():
    def __init__(self, questions_file='questions.csv'):
        self.questions_file = questions_file
        self._build_gui() # build_gui function
        self.clock() # run clock function
        self.current_question_index=0 # question index counter
        self.points = 0 # number points counter
        self.num_right = 0 # number questions correct counter
        self.tries = 2 # number tries counter
        self.user_answer = tk.IntVar()
        self.root.mainloop()

    # show instructions for StudyStar⭐️
    def about(self):
        messagebox.showinfo(title="About StudyStar⭐️", message="Put instructions here!")
        return
    
    # question from .csv file
    def get_question(self):
        # print(self.questions[self.current_question_index]) #DEBUG
        return self.questions[self.current_question_index][0]

    # options from .csv file
    def get_options(self):
        print(self.current_question_index)
        print(self.questions[self.current_question_index])
        return self.questions[self.current_question_index][1:-1]

    # correct answer from .csv file
    def get_current_answer(self):
        return self.questions[self.current_question_index][-1]

    # start showing questions
    def start(self):
        self.questions = qm.get_questions(self.questions_file)
        current_question = self.get_question()
        self._update_question(current_question)
        options = self.get_options()
        self._make_options(options)
        self.qset_name_button.grid_forget() # hide load and start button
        self.qset_name_entry.grid_forget() # hide qset name text entry widget
        self.qset_name_label.grid_forget() # hide qset name label
        self.qset_filename_label.grid(row=15) # show reading from filename
        self.submit_button.grid(row=6) # show check answer button
        self.questions_box.grid(row=2,column=0) # show questions box
        
        # progress bar
        self.my_progress = ttk.Progressbar(self.root, orient=HORIZONTAL,length=400, mode='determinate')
        self.my_progress.grid(row=12, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.number_of_questions = len(self.questions) #total number questions in set
        self.points_possible = self.number_of_questions * 10 #total points possible

    # increase step of progress bar
    def step(self):
        self.my_progress['value'] += self.number_of_questions

    # is answer correct?
    def is_answer_correct(self):
        return self.get_current_answer() == self.get_options()[self.user_answer.get()-1]

    # update answer label correct/incorrect
    def _update_answer_label(self):
        while True:
            if self.is_answer_correct():
                status = 'Correct! +10 points!'
                self.answer_label.config(text=status, font='Helvetica 14 bold', fg='#ffbb00')
                self.points = self.points + 10
                self.num_right = self.num_right + 1
                stop_asking = False
                self.tries = 2
                break
            else:
                status = 'Incorrect! -5 points! You have 1 more try.'
                self.points = self.points - 5   
                self.answer_label.config(text=status,font='Helvetica 14 bold', fg='#ffbb00')
                self.tries = self.tries - 1
                if self.tries == 0:
                    status = 'Incorrect! -5 points! No tries left.'
                    status += ' The correct answer is: {}'.format(self.get_current_answer())
                    self.answer_label.config(text=status, fg='#ffbb00', font='Helvetica 14 bold')
                    self.points = self.points - 5
                    stop_asking = True
                    self.tries = 2
                    break
            
            if stop_asking:
                self.tries = 2
                break
            
    def _update_questions_remaining(self):
        pass

    def _update_question(self,question):
        self.questions_label.config(text=question)

    def get_next_question(self):
        self.current_question_index += 1
        if self.current_question_index == len(self.questions):# if last question has been answered
            #self._update_question.grid_forget()
            self.questions_box.grid_forget() # hide questions box
            self.my_progress.grid_forget() # hide progress bar
            self.qset_filename_label.grid_forget() # hide reading from filename text
            self.study_again_button.grid(row=2, column=1) # show study again button
            tk.Label(self.root, text="Congratulations - you finished the quiz! ",font='Helvetica 16 bold', bg='#375e97', fg='#ffbb00').grid(row=3) # show questions correct
            tk.Label(self.root, text=str(self.num_right) + " " + "out of" + " " + str(self.number_of_questions) + " " + "questions were answered correctly.",font='Helvetica 16 bold', bg='#375e97', fg='white').grid(row=4)
            tk.Label(self.root, text="Total number of points:" + " " + str(self.points) + " " + "out of" + " " + str(self.points_possible),font='Helvetica 16 bold', bg='#375e97', fg='white').grid(row=5) #show total points
            return
        else:
            self._update_questions_remaining()
        self._update_question(self.get_question())
        self._update_options(self.get_options())

    # check answer and update label
    def check_and_update(self):
        self._update_answer_label()
        self.root.after(1500,self.get_next_question)

    # build GUI components
    def _build_gui(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('600x300') # window size
        self.root.title("StudyStar⭐️") # window title
        self.root.configure(background = '#375e97') # set background color
        self.welcome_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="StudyStar⭐️", font='Helvetica 18 bold', bg='#375e97', fg='white').grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20)
        self.user_answer = tk.IntVar()
        self.questions_box = tk.Frame(self.root, bg='#375e97')
        
        self.questions_label = tk.Label(self.questions_box, bg='#375e97',fg='#ffbb00', font='Helvetica 20 bold')
        self.questions_label.grid(row=0)
        self.option_buttons = []
        self.answer_label = tk.Label(self.questions_box, bg='#375e97')
        self.answer_label.grid(row=5)

        self.qset_name_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Enter the name of your .csv file:", bg='#375e97', fg='white')
        self.qset_name_label.grid(row=2)
        self.qset_name_entry = Entry(self.root, width=20, highlightbackground='#375e97') # I DO need the entry widget as attribute so I can get it's text later!
        self.qset_name_entry.insert(0, "questions.csv") # default text
        self.qset_name_entry.config(state=DISABLED) # make text entry read only
        self.qset_name_entry.grid(row=3, column=0)
        
        self.qset_name_button = Button(self.root, text="Load and Start", font='Helvetica 16', fg='#3f681c', highlightbackground='#375e97', command=self.start) 
        self.qset_name_button.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=1)

        self.filename = self.qset_name_entry.get()
        self.qset_filename_label = tk.Label(self.root, text= "Reading questions from:" + " " + self.filename, bg='#375e97', fg='white')

        # Submit button
        self.submit_button = tk.Button(self.questions_box, text="Check Answer", font='Helvetica 16 bold', fg='#3f681c', highlightbackground='#375e97', command=lambda:[self.check_and_update(), self.step()])

        # Start Quiz button
        self.side_box = tk.Frame(self.root, bg='#375e97')
        #self.start_button = tk.Button(self.side_box, text="Begin Studying",font='Helvetica 16', fg='#3f681c', highlightbackground='#375e97', command=self.start)
        #self.start_button.grid(row=3)
        #self.side_box.grid(row=3,column=1)

        # Quit Quiz button
        self.quit_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Quit Quiz", font='Helvetica 16', fg='red', highlightbackground='#375e97', command=self.root.quit)
        self.quit_button.grid(row=0, column= 1)

        # About Quiz button
        self.about_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Instructions", font='Helvetica 16', highlightbackground='#375e97', command=self.about)
        self.about_button.grid(row=1, column=1)

        # Study Again button
        self.study_again_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Study Again",font='Helvetica 16', fg='#3f681c', highlightbackground='#375e97', command=None) #TODO

        # clock
    def clock(self):
        self.hour = time.strftime("%H") # hour
        self.minute = time.strftime("%M") # minute
        self.second = time.strftime("%S") # second
        self.am_pm = time.strftime("%p") # am/pm

        self.clock_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="", font='Helvetica 16 bold', fg="black", bg="#ffbb00")
        self.clock_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20)
        self.clock_label.config(text=self.hour + ":" + self.minute + ":" +self.second + " " + self.am_pm)
        self.clock_label.after(1000, self.clock) # update clock

    def _make_options(self,options_list):
        for option,index in zip(options_list,range(len(options_list))):
            self.option_buttons.append(tk.Radiobutton(self.questions_box, text=option, font='Helvetica 16', bg='#375e97',fg='white', value=index+1, variable=self.user_answer))
            self.option_buttons[-1].grid(row=index+1)

    def _update_options(self,options_list):
        self.user_answer.set(7)
        for option_button,option,index in zip(self.option_buttons,options_list,range(len(options_list))):
            option_button.config(text=option, value=index+1)




# run app
# Create an object of the MainQuizApp class to begin the program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainQuizApp()
```

questions_model.py

```
import csv
import random

def get_questions(filename):
    questions = None
    try:
        with open(filename,'r') as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
            questions = list(reader)
            lines = len(questions)
            random.shuffle(questions) # randomize question order
    except:
        print("unable to process request")

    return questions




if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_questions('questions.csv'))
```

Comment: I don’t understand what you are asking. It seems you have already implemented this?! Why don’t you use `self.filename` instead of a hardcoded filename?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I thought it was that simple, also, but when I try changing the hardcoded questions.csv to self.filename, it does not work. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Use the tkinter `filedialog.askopenfilename()` file dialog to allow the user to select (or type-in) the name of a csv file.

Comment: @martineau THANK YOU! this worked perfectly!

Comment: That's good to hear. Making your app "data-driven" like this is a smart thing to do, IMO.